# Will HttpContext.Current.Session work with load balancer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Is it safe to store user data into `HttpContext.Current.Session` when load balancer is in place?

If not, what is the right approach to store user data in memory across multiple web servers?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use Session State, but you want to use external Session State provider instead of default [InProc mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) - values and variables are stored in memory on the local Web server.

You have few options -

- StateServer
- [SQLServer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604)
- [Custom mode using Redis Cache like Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/).

Comment: @mimo : One Thing to note here, Session related events in Global.asax.cs will not execute once you set it to anything apart from In-Proc

Answer (score 2):

Some load balancers can use ip affinity, that means that all request from a given ip address go to the same server. If you have such load balancer with ip affinity enabled, you can use in-proc session variables. If you don't, then you'll need to use StateServer or SQL Server session providers.